# Conversion between character and int in Java

Tags: java

You cannot convert from int to char, so this would be illegal
`int i = 88; char c = i;`,

However this is allowed `char c = 88;`.

Isn't a plain number and `int` literal? How is this allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char` is effectively an unsigned 16-bit integer type in Java.

Like other integer types, you can perform an assignment conversion from an integer constant to any integer type so long as it's in the appropriate range. That's why

```
byte b = 10;
```

works too.

From the JLS, [section 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a
>   constant expression (§15.28) of type
>   byte, short, char or int :
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may
>     be used if the type of the variable is
>     byte, short, or char, and the value of
>     the constant expression is
>     representable in the type of the
>     variable.
> - A narrowing primitive
>     conversion followed by a boxing
>     conversion may be used if the type of
>     the variable is :
>
>   - Byte and the value
>       of the constant expression is
>       representable in the type byte.
>   - Short
>       and the value of the constant
>       expression is representable in the
>       type short.
>   - Character and the value of
>       the constant expression is
>       representable in the type char.

Comment: char does not belong to the integer group. My understanding is as follows, since the compiler can check the value of a literal it can perform this conversion smoothly, in other types it can lead to loss of data, is this correct

Comment: @user265260: Um yes, char *does* belong to the integer group. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2 - "The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1)."

Comment: Probably a side question but why is `char c = 2.0;` not allowed.

Comment: @user265260: Because that's a constant expression of type `double`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, converting from `int` to `char` is legal, it just requires an explicit cast because it can potentially lose data:

```
int i = 88; 
char c = (char) i;
```

However, with the literal, the compiler *knows* whether it will fit into a `char` without losing data and only complains when you use a literal that is too big to fit into a `char`:

```
char c = 70000; // compiler error
```

Comment: Don't think it's all about losing data, a byte that can fit in a char cannot be assigned to char either

Comment: @GeorgianBenetatos that's because the range of `byte` (-128..127) is not completely contained within the range of `char` (0..65535) so there _is_ a risk of lossy conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the literals for integer or smaller than int as byte ,short and char is **int**. Understand the following in this way.

code:

```
  byte a = 10;//compile fine
  byte b= 11;//compile fine
  byte c = a+b;//compiler error[says that result of **a+b** is **int**]
```

the same happens for any mathematical operations as of 'Divide', 'multiply', and other arithmetic operation. so cast the result to get the literal in desired data type

```
byte c = (byte)(a+b);
```

So that the same reason why the value int need to have primitive cast to change the value in char.
Hope this make some sense.